# Get the last day of the month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the last day of the month given as a date in SQL. If I have the first day of the month, I can do something like this:

```
DATEADD(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH,'2009-05-01',1), -1)
```

But does anyone know how to generalize it so I can find the last day of the month for any given date?

Comment: Why is this query not general ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here's my version. No string manipulation or casting required, just one call each to the `DATEADD`, `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions:

```
DECLARE @test DATETIME
SET @test = GETDATE()  -- or any other date

SELECT DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(@test) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(@test), -1)
```

---

This works by taking the number of months that have passed since the initial date in SQL's date system (1/1/1990), then adding that number of months to the date "-1" (12/31/1899) using the DATEADD function, which returns a proper datetime at the corresponding month's end (that of the date you specified). It relies on the fact that December always ends on the 31st and there are no months longer than that.

Comment: I can't understand how this query returns the last day of a month, although it works of course. Could you further explain it a bit please?

Comment: If you use SQL Server >= 2012, then use EOMONTH (see the answer from Martin Smith) instead

Comment: The solution takes as base the first known date by SQL Server (1900-01-01). Then it calculates the number of months that have passed until your given date (@test) by fours steps:

1. Calculate how many years have passed: given year - 1900
2. Multiply the result of step 1 by 12 to transform it to months
3. Add to result of step 2 the months of given date
4. The magic number is finally converted to DATETIME by using DATEADD function removing one month

Answer (score 98):

From SQL Server 2012 you can use the [EOMONTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh213020.aspx) function.

> Returns the last day of the month that contains the specified date,
>   with an optional offset.

**Syntax**

```
EOMONTH ( start_date [, month_to_add ] )
```

> How ... I can find the last day of the month for any given date?

```
SELECT EOMONTH(@SomeGivenDate)
```

Answer (score 14):

You could get the days in the date by using the [DAY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx) function:

```
dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(date), date)))
```

Comment: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Comment: I fixed the syntax for you. DATEADD is `(datepart, distance, date)`.

Answer (score 6):

Works in SQL server

```
Declare @GivenDate datetime
SET @GivenDate = GETDATE()

Select DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @GivenDate),0) --First day of the month 

Select DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM, -1, @GivenDate),-1) --Last day of the month
```

Comment: First date (not day) of a month is always the 01. Why do you need a function to find that ?

Answer (score 5):

For SQL server 2012 or above use EOMONTH to get the last date of month

SQL query to display end date of current month

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATE = GETDATE()
SELECT EOMONTH (@currentDate) AS CurrentMonthED
```

SQL query to display end date of Next month

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATE = GETDATE()
SELECT EOMONTH (@currentDate, 1 ) AS NextMonthED
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a old question but here is another solution that works for me

```
SET @dtDate = "your date"
DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dtDate)+1,0))
```

And if some one is looking for different examples here is a link http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/

I hope this helps some one else.
stackoverflow Rocks!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Based on the statements:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @x)           -- Add a month to the supplied date @x
```

and

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,  0 - DAY(@x), @x)  -- Get last day of month previous to the supplied date @x
```

how about adding a month to date @x and then retrieving the last day of the month previous to that (i.e. The last day of the month of the supplied date)

```
DECLARE @x  DATE = '20-Feb-2012' 
SELECT DAY(DATEADD(DAY,  0 - DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @x)), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @x)))
```

Note: This was test using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2):

Just extend your formula out a little bit:

```
dateadd(day, -1,
    dateadd(month, 1,
        cast(month('5/15/2009') as varchar(2)) + 
        '/1/' + 
        cast(year('5/15/2009') as varchar(4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, using Microsoft SQL Server 2005:

```
DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,'2009-05-01')+1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

WinSQL to get last day of last month (i.e today is 2017-02-09, returns 2017-01-31:
 Select dateadd(day,-day(today()),today())

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the following query, it will give you everything you want :)

```
Declare @a date =dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0)
Print('First day of Current Month:')
Print(@a)
Print('')
set @a = dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm,0,getdate())+1,-1)
Print('Last day of Current Month:')
Print(@a)
Print('')

Print('First day of Last Month:')
set @a = dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm,0,getdate())-1,0)
Print(@a)
Print('')

Print('Last day of Last Month:') 
set @a = dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm,0,getdate()),-1)
Print(@a)
Print('')


Print('First day of Current Week:')
set @a = dateadd(ww, Datediff(ww,0,getdate()),0)
Print(@a)
Print('')

Print('Last day of Current Week:')
set @a = dateadd(ww, Datediff(ww,0,getdate())+1,-1)
Print(@a)
Print('')

Print('First day of Last Week:')
set @a =  dateadd(ww, Datediff(ww,0,getdate())-1,0)
Print(@a)
Print('')

Print('Last day of Last Week:')
set @a =  dateadd(ww, Datediff(ww,0,getdate()),-1)
Print(@a)
```

Answer (score 1):

WinSQL: I wanted to return all records for last month:

```
where DATE01 between dateadd(month,-1,dateadd(day,1,dateadd(day,-day(today()),today()))) and dateadd(day,-day(today()),today())
```

This does the same thing:

```
where month(DATE01) = month(dateadd(month,-1,today())) and year(DATE01) = year(dateadd(month,-1,today()))
```

Answer (score 1):

This query can also be used.

```
DECLARE @SelectedDate DATE =  GETDATE()

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, - DAY(@SelectedDate), DATEADD(MONTH, 1 , @SelectedDate)) EndOfMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

--## Useful Date Functions

SELECT

```
GETDATE() AS [DateTime],

CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS [Date],

DAY(GETDATE()) AS [Day of Month],

FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMMM') AS [Month Name],

FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMM') AS [Month Short Name],

FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MM') AS [Month No],

YEAR(GETDATE()) AS [Year],

CAST(DATEADD(DD,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS [Month Start Date],

EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AS [Month End Date],

CAST(DATEADD(M,-1,DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(M,0,GETDATE()),0)) AS DATE) AS [Previous Month Start Date],

CAST(DATEADD(S,-1,DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(M,0,GETDATE()),0)) AS DATE) AS [Previous Month End Date],

CAST(DATEADD(M,+1,DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(M,0,GETDATE()),0)) AS DATE) AS [Next Month Start Date],

CAST(DATEADD(D,-1,DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(M,0,GETDATE())+2,0)) AS DATE) AS [Next Month End Date],

CAST(DATEADD(WW, DATEDIFF(WW,0,GETDATE()),0) AS DATE) AS [First Day of Current Week],

CAST(DATEADD(WW, DATEDIFF(WW,0,GETDATE())+1,-1) AS DATE) AS [Last Day of Current Week],

CAST(DATEADD(WW, DATEDIFF(WW,0,GETDATE())-1,0) AS DATE) AS [First Day of Last Week],

CAST(DATEADD(WW, DATEDIFF(WW,0,GETDATE()),-1) AS DATE) AS [Last Day of Last Week],

CAST(DATEADD(WW, DATEDIFF(WW,0,GETDATE())+1,0) AS DATE) AS [First Day of Next Week],

CAST(DATEADD(WW, DATEDIFF(WW,0,GETDATE())+2,-1) AS DATE) AS [Last Day of Next Week]
```

Comment: There are currently 21 answers with the top-voted answer having over 80 upvotes. What does your answer add to the thread? What are you doing that’s not covered by the other answers? Please [edit] your answer to help explain WHY these are useful date functions and HOW they answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

```
select DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(day,(0-(DATEPART(dd,'2008-02-12')-1)),'2008-02-12')))
```

Raj

Answer (score 0):

using sql server 2005, this works for me:

```
select dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,YOUR_DATE)+1,0))
```

Basically, you get the number of months from the beginning of (SQL Server) time for YOUR_DATE. Then add one to it to get the sequence number of the next month. Then you add this number of months to 0 to get a date that is the first day of the next month. From this you then subtract a day to get to the last day of YOUR_DATE.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server, here is another way to find last day of month :

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE())- day(DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take some base date which is the 31st of some month e.g. '20011231'. Then use the
following procedure (I have given 3 identical examples below, only the @dt value differs).

```
declare @dt datetime;

set @dt = '20140312'

SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '20011231', @dt), '20011231');



set @dt = '20140208'

SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '20011231', @dt), '20011231');



set @dt = '20140405'

SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '20011231', @dt), '20011231');
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote following function, it works.

It returns datetime data type. Zero hour, minute, second, miliseconds.

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[fn_GetLastDate]
(
    @date datetime
)
returns datetime
as
begin

declare @result datetime

 select @result = CHOOSE(month(@date),  
 DATEADD(DAY, 31 -day(@date), @date),
 IIF(YEAR(@date) % 4 = 0, DATEADD(DAY, 29 -day(@date), @date), DATEADD(DAY, 28 -day(@date), @date)), 
 DATEADD(DAY, 31 -day(@date), @date) ,
 DATEADD(DAY, 30 -day(@date), @date), 
 DATEADD(DAY, 31 -day(@date), @date),
 DATEADD(DAY, 30 -day(@date), @date), 
 DATEADD(DAY, 31 -day(@date), @date),
 DATEADD(DAY, 31 -day(@date), @date),
 DATEADD(DAY, 30 -day(@date), @date),
 DATEADD(DAY, 31 -day(@date), @date),
 DATEADD(DAY, 30 -day(@date), @date), 
 DATEADD(DAY, 31 -day(@date), @date))

 return convert(date, @result)

end
```

It's very easy to use. 
2 example:

```
select [dbo].[fn_GetLastDate]('2016-02-03 12:34:12')

select [dbo].[fn_GetLastDate](GETDATE())
```

Comment: Why on earth would you write your own function to do this when you can just cast EOMONTH to DATETIME? select [dbo].[fn_GetLastDate]('1900-02-03') Won't return the correct result.

Comment: Martin, you are right. I don't want to give an alternative advice to the world:). Just, I need this function before Sql server 2012 versions.

Comment: It won't work on versions before 2012 as it uses CHOOSE.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the most voted answer at below link I came up with the following solution:

```
 declare  @mydate date= '2020-11-09';
  SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate)+1, -1) AS lastOfMonth
```

link: [How can I select the first day of a month in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer that worked in regular SQL, so I brute forced an answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
WHERE (MONTH(o.OrderDate) IN ('01','03','05','07','08','10','12') AND DAY(o.OrderDate) = '31')
    OR (MONTH(o.OrderDate) IN ('04','06','09','11') AND DAY(o.OrderDate) = '30')
    OR (MONTH(o.OrderDate) IN ('02') AND DAY(o.OrderDate) = '28')
```

Answer (score 0):

user a function EOMONTH(GETDATE())

```
SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
---Start/End of previous Month 
Declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

set @StartDate = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1,0) 
set @EndDate = EOMONTH (DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1,0)) 

SELECT @StartDate,@EndDate
```