# How can I select the first day of a month in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

How can one select the first day of the month of a given DateTime variable?

---

I know it's quite easy to do using this kind of code:

```
select CAST(CAST(YEAR(@mydate) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
+ '/' + CAST(MONTH(@mydate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01' AS DATETIME)
```

This is not very elegant, and not very fast either.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 762, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0) AS StartOfMonth
```

Comment: [There is a cardinality estimation bug to be aware of if using this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18242413/73226)

Comment: It should be noted the bug mentioned by Martin Smith can "only" affect performance, not correctness.

Comment: Here is an [explanation on why and how this works](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2010/03/grouping-and-rounding-dates/).

Comment: Discovered this does not work with out of range datetime2 values. `select DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, cast('0002-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' as datetime2)), 0)
` will throw an error.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering `SELECT EOMONTH(@mydate) AS EndOfMonth` will give you the last day of the month.

Comment: The noted cardinality estimation bug just caused 40 queries to pile up and a system to have an outage, so I'd strongly consider finding another method if performance / availability is important to you.

Comment: How can I determine if the noted cardinality estimation bug will affect me? It is marked as fixed in 2010. Does that mean that only SQL Server 2012 and newer are safe, or is it possible that a 2008 server may have been patched?

Answer (score 217):

In addition to all the above answer, a way based on a function introduced in `sql 2012`

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@mydate),MONTH(@mydate),1)
```

Answer (score 152):

Starting with SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@mydate,-1))
```

Comment: This looks more efficient and straightforward. Also, with the help of `EOMONTH(@mydate,-1)`, we can get the first date of the next or previous month as well.

Answer (score 19):

From SQL Server 2022 you can use [`DATETRUNC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT DATETRUNC(month, @mydate)
```

for this need

Comment: 2022, gosh you are updated :)

Answer (score 16):

Simple Query:

```
SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
-- Instead of GetDate you can put any date.
```

Comment: I like this.....select DATEFROMPARTS(year(getdate()),month(getdate()),'01')
,convert(date,dateadd(day,1-day(getdate()),getdate()))
,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
,DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

Answer (score 15):

The casting of a string (i.e. "5/1/2009") to datetime is certainly more legible but we found code a while back that would return the first of the month...

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
//...
SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,@Date), 0)
```

Answer (score 8):

This might be a new function, but you can also use old functions :

```
select DATEFROMPARTS(year(@mydate),month(@mydate),'01')
```

If the date in the variable was for example `'2017-10-29'`
it would return a date of `'2017-10-01'`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT @myDate - DAY(@myDate) + 1
```

Comment: Really simple and elegant solution but keep in mind that this also returns the time portion of the date if specified in the variable.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Besides the extra closing bracket, I get this error: `Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int`. I guess it's because you're trying to use the `-` operator on a date?

Comment: I don't know how good it is in terms of performance, but it certainly does the job.

Comment: @Sam, you've got a clash because simple arithmetic (+, -)  works on datetimes, not on dates.

Comment: You need to declare @myDate as a DateTime rather than just a Date.  Which means your date will have time in it - and that may not be desirable (you can always cast it out)

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to go for SQL Server 2012+ you can try solution I used:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 5):

It is probably quite fast.  Why not create it as a sql function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFirstDayOfMonth] ( @InputDate    DATETIME )
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN

    RETURN CAST(CAST(YEAR(@InputDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + 
                CAST(MONTH(@InputDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01' AS DATETIME)

END
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

First and last day of the current month:

```sql
select dateadd(mm, -1,dateadd(dd, +1, eomonth(getdate()))) as FirstDay, 
eomonth(getdate()) as LastDay
```

Answer (score 3):

This works too:

```
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(DAY,@mydate)-1)*(-1),@mydate) AS FirstOfMonth
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use this

1. For Server 2012

   ```
   DATEFROMPARTS(year('2015-06-30'),month('2015-06-30'),1)
   ```
2. Before Server 2012

   ```
   select  cast(cast(year('2015-06-30') as varchar(4))+'-'+ cast(month('2015-06-30') as varchar(2))+'-01' as smalldatetime)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I used GETDATE() as a date to work with, you can replace it with the date which you need. 
Here's how this works: First we format the date in YYYYMMDD... format truncating to keep just the 6 leftmost characters in order to keep just the YYYYMM portion, and then append '01' as the month - and voila! you have the first day of the current month.

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112) +'01' AS DATETIME) AS StartOfMonth
```

BTW, performance is great on this!

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @startofmonth date
SET @startofmonth = DATEADD(dd,1,EOMONTH(Getdate(),-2))
```

The -2 will get you the first day of last month.  ie, getdate() is 10/15/18.  Your results would be 9/1/18.  Change to -1 and your results would be 10/1/18.  0 would be the start of next month, 11/1/2018.. etc etc.

or

```
DECLARE @startofmonth date
SET @startofmonth = DATEADD(dd,1,EOMONTH(@mydate,-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below function for getting 1st day of current month:

```
DECLARE @mydate date
set @mydate=GETDATE()
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@mydate),MONTH(@mydate),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEADD (DAY, -1 * (DAY(GETDATE()) - 1), GETDATE())
```

.....................................................................

If you dont want the time, then convert it to DATE or if want to make to time to 0:00:00, Convert to DATE and then back to DATETIME.

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME,  
CONVERT (DATE, DATEADD (DAY, -1 * (DAY(GETDATE()) - 1),
GETDATE())))
```

Change GETDATE() to the date you want

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at this today, and using SQL server 2012 or newer you have the EOMONTH function which makes things easier:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()))) as firstdateofmonth
```

You can change GETDATE() with whatever date variable you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here we can use below query to the first date of the month and last date of the month.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(Getdate(),-1)) as 'FD',Cast(Getdate()-1 as Date)
as 'LD'
```

Answer (score 1):

If using SQL Server 2012 or above;

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
----Last Day of Previous Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
LastDay_PreviousMonth
----Last Day of Current Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
LastDay_CurrentMonth
----Last Day of Next Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+2,0))
LastDay_NextMonth
```

Comment: But the OP is looking for the first day of the month. For last day, you could just use EOMONTH() - has been this way since 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing the following query:

`SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE-INTERVAL 1 DAY),INTERVAL 1 DAY),INTERVAL -1 MONTH)`

Answer (score 0):

select CONVERT(date,DATEADD(dd,-(DATEPART(dd,getdate())-1),getdate()),120)

This function will provide you date part of start date of the month

Answer (score 0):

This query should work very well on MySQL:

```
SELECT concat(left(curdate(),7),'-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something different! Use Format.

```
DECLARE @Date Date =GetDate();
SELECT CONVERT(Date,Format(@Date,'yyyyMM01'));
```

We can remove the convert if we are casting to Date Column or variable

```
DECLARE @Date Date =GetDate();
SELECT @Date =Format(@Date,'yyyyMM01');
SELECT [Date]=@Date
```

Have Fun :)

Answer (score 0):

For **DATE** type in **any** SQL Server

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(@mydate), @mydate)
```

In 99.9% of cases, input parameters with time are not needed because **DATE** does not require explicit conversion to >= < and BETWEEN

It is also convenient to write `WHERE CAST(Table.DateTime AS DATE) BETWEEN @DateB AND @DateE` , this expression gives **Index Seek** YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 >= AND <= YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: pros:
1) there is no need to count from time 0, which is not only not intuitive, but also caused problems for the commentators of the 1st answer
2) brevity without using EOMONTH, etc. which is not in older versions like 2008
3) why DATE is sufficient, convenient and effective written in the answer

Comment: You should [edit] your answer and post the "pros" rather than posting them in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Future googlers, on MySQL, try this:

```
select date_sub(ref_date, interval day(ref_date)-1 day) as day1;
```

Comment: This is a `sql-server` question, `date_sub` and `interval` are `mysql`.

Comment: Good, point, I edited the response. I think it's still relevant for the thread.

Answer (score -1):

I personal recommended that the sql below because when i try use date function in the condition clause, its slow down my query speed very much.

anyway feel free to try this.

```
select CONCAT(DATEPART(YYYY,@mydate),'-',DATEPART(MM,@mydate),'-01')
```

Answer (score -1):

Not to compete with any of the great minds here, but a simple suggestion slightly different that the accepted answer above.

```
select dateadd(day, -(datepart(day,@date)+1,@date)
```

Answer (score -1):

I like to use `FORMAT`, you can even specify a time

```
SELECT FORMAT(@myDate,'yyyy-MM-01 06:00') first_of_a_month
```

Answer (score -1):

In Sql Server 2012,

```
 select getdate()-DATEPART(day, getdate())+1

 select DATEADD(Month,1,getdate())-DATEPART(day, getdate())
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone still looking for an answer, this works like a charm and does away with any dateadds. The timestamp is optional, in case it needs specifying, but works without as well.

```
SELECT left(convert(varchar, getdate(),23),7)+'-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score -1):

**Get First Date and Last Date in  the Date we pass as parameter  in  SQL**

```
     @date DATETIME
    SELECT @date = GETDATE()
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@date)-1),@date),105) AS value,
    'First Day of Current Month' AS name
    UNION
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@date))),
    DATEADD(mm,1,@date)),105),
    'Last Day of Current Month'
    GO


      **OutPut**

12/01/2019  First Day of Current Month
12/31/2019  Last Day of Current Month
```

Answer (score -4):

Try the following:

```
select trunc(sysdate,'MM') 
from dual;
```

Comment: The question is about SQL Server, which does not have a `trunc` function. Always make sure you check the question tags.

Answer (score -4):

Try the following:

```sql
select trunc(to_date('23-03-2021','DD-MM-YYYY'),'MM') from dual;
```