# Get Start date of a month between start date and end Date

Tags: sql-server

I want to get only the start date of month between selected date

ex :

```
start date = 2012 -05-01
end date = 2013-04-01
```

I want like this

```
   Dates :
   2012 -05-01
   2012 -06-01
   2012 -07-01 .....
   2013 -01-01 .....
   2012 -05-01
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

CTE will do the trick

```
   Declare @beginDt SmallDatetime = '13 Jan 2012'
   Declare @endDt SmallDatetime = '2 Apr 2013';
   With MonthList(aMon)
      As
      (Select DateAdd(month, datediff(month, 0, @beginDt), 31)
         Union All
       Select DateAdd(month, 1, aMon) From MonthList
       Where DateAdd(month, 1, aMon) < @endDt)
       Select aMon from MonthList
```

Comment: Be aware of the maximum recursion of a CTE. You can't generate 9 years data with this code.

Answer (score 0):

First, [create a calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html). Then you can write a simple query:

```
select [Date]
from dbo.Calendar
where IsFirstDayOfMonth = 1 and [Date] between '20120501' and '20130401'
```

This query is much clearer than using using a function-based solution and a calendar table has many other uses too.