# Query runs slow with date expression, but fast with string literal

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am running a query with below condition in SQL Server 2008.

```
Where FK.DT = CAST(DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, getdate()), 0) as DATE)
```

Query takes forever to run with above condition, but if just say

```
Where FK.DT = '2013-05-01'
```

it runs great in 2 mins. `FK.DT` key contains values of only starting data of the month.

Any help, I am just clueless why this is happening.

Comment: What is the data type of `DT`? Is the column indexed? Did you look at actual execution plans with the expression and with the string literal, and compare them? What happens if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the statement?

Comment: Also, please add both execution plans (XML format).

Comment: Bets on DT being varchar?

Comment: @GarethD while I agree, note that this happens for conversions to `DATETIME`, but not to `DATE`. Try this: `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;
  DECLARE @d DATE = '2013-05-01', @dt DATETIME = '2013-05-01'; SELECT @d, @dt;`

Comment: I once answered this before in a comment. A bunch of high ranking people didn't believe me. But you sometimes need to put your expression in a variable to get the best performance.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk you mean like the second option on Aaron's answer?

Comment: @Lamak second part is basically the same as the question suggests. Problem is that it will not work inside a view.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I was replying to your comment saying "you sometimes need to put your expression in a variable to get the best performance", which is what is used on that part of the answer

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I didn't know the user was using a view?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks, I deleted the comment because I couldn't recreate the different interpretations. I now realise that this is because I was using DATE. For anyone else's sake, my original comment (not as an answer, just a note really) suggested using the culture invariant date format `yyyyMMdd` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd` to avoid conversion errors in the future.

Comment: Can you please clarify if `DT` is a `DATE` column or a `DATETIME` column?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This could work better:

```
Where FK.DT = cast(getdate() + 1 - datepart(day, getdate()) as date)
```

Unless you are running with trace flag 4199 on there is [a bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/630583/incorrect-estimate-with-condition-that-includes-datediff) that affects the cardinality estimates. At the time of writing

```
SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, getdate(), 0), 0), 
       DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Returns

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1786-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2013-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

The bug is that the predicate in the question uses the first date rather than the second when deriving the cardinality estimates. So for the following setup.

```
CREATE TABLE FK
(
ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
DT DATE,
Filler CHAR(1000) NULL,
UNIQUE (DT,ID)
)

INSERT INTO FK (DT)
SELECT TOP (1000000) DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, getdate(), 0), 0)
FROM master..spt_values o1, master..spt_values o2
UNION ALL
SELECT               DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

#### Query 1

```
SELECT COUNT(Filler)
FROM FK
WHERE FK.DT = CAST(DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, getdate()), 0) AS DATE)
```

[image: Plan 1]

Estimates that the number of matching rows will be 100,000. This is the number that match the date `'1786-06-01'`.

But both of the following queries

```
SELECT COUNT(Filler)
FROM FK
WHERE FK.DT = CAST(GETDATE() + 1 - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) AS DATE)

SELECT COUNT(Filler)
FROM FK
WHERE FK.DT = CAST(DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, getdate()), 0) AS DATE)  
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 4199)
```

Give this plan

[image: Plan 2]

Due to the much more accurate cardinality estimates the plan now just does a single index seek rather than a full scan.

Comment: Thanks so much this worked, what's the difference here, even my function was also doing same, would like to know for reference.

Comment: @user2158642 to be honest, I wish I knew. Just used this workaround when I ran into the same problem

Comment: @AaronBertrand as I said a bunch of high ranking people didn't believe me last time I posted this. I was unable to prove it even though I browsed for hours.

Comment: well I am sure you don't believe it. None believed last time I wrote it. However I found someone who had the same problem I had. I resolved it the same way I originally solved it, and it worked.

Comment: @AaronBertrand This is clearly some sort of bug in T-sql. Maybe the plan wasn't working, I have encountered the same problem a couple of times. This was my workaround and it seems to have worked in this case and in my cases. Downvoting this answer is just rediculos

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you very much for following up on this, I really appriciate it.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - No problem. Looks like an interesting estimation bug. I took the liberty of editing a demo into your answer.

Comment: And @MikaelEriksson pointed out in the [dba.se] chat that this is a [fixed bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2481274/sv) but you need trace flag 4199 enabled to get the fix.

Comment: Very sorry I doubted you. Updated my answer.

Comment: [Also blogged about this](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/datediff-bug).

Comment: The reason that `DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, getdate(), 0), 0)` returns a 1786 date is due to an incorrect sign. The corrected expression would be `DATEADD(m, -DATEDIFF(m, getdate(), 0), 0)`, which calculates the intended result and (presumably) resolves the cardinality estimate issue.

Answer (score 13):

**In most cases, the below probably applies. In this *specific* case, this is an optimizer bug involving `DATEDIFF`.** Details [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2481274) and [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/630583/incorrect-estimate-with-condition-that-includes-datediff). Sorry for doubting t-clausen.dk, but his answer simply wasn't an intuitive and logical solution without knowing about the existence of the bug.

So assuming `DT` is actually `DATE` and not something silly like `VARCHAR` or - worse still - `NVARCHAR` - this is probably because you have a plan cached that used a very different date value when first executed, therefore chose a plan catering to a very different typical data distribution. There are ways you can overcome this:

1. Force a recompile of the plan by adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. You might only have to do this once, but then the plan you get might not be optimal for other parameters. The downside to leaving the option there all the time is that you then pay the compile cost every time the query runs. In a lot of cases this is not substantial, and I'll often choose to pay a known small cost rather than sometimes have a query that runs slightly faster and other times it runs extremely slow.

   ```
   ...
   WHERE FK.DT = CAST(... AS DATE) OPTION (RECOMPILE);
   ```
2. Use a variable first (no need for an explicit `CONVERT` to `DATE` here, and please use `MONTH` instead of shorthand like `m` - that habit can lead to real funny behavior if you haven't memorized what all of the abbreviations do, for example I bet `y` and `w` don't produce the results you'd expect):

   ```
   DECLARE @dt DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0);

   ...
   WHERE FK.DT = @dt;
   ```

   However in this case the same thing could happen - parameter sniffing could coerce a sub-optimal plan to be used for different parameters representing different data skew.
3. You could also experiment with `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@dt = '2013-08-01'))`, which would coerce SQL Server into considering this value instead of the one that was used to compile the cached plan, but this would require a hard-coded string literal, which will only help you for the rest of August, at which point you'd need to update the value. You could also consider `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for reply, FK.DT is actually a date field.I tried the  too before, but same issue query kept on running and this filed is not an index filed.

Comment: @user2158642 What is "tried the too"? And if you're querying on this column frequently, why don't you consider indexing it? Typically this is why we have indexes - to make our queries more efficient and predictable. Seeing the *actual* (not estimated) plans for the two versions of the query (one slow, one fast) will certainly help us not make stabbing guesses at the air...

Comment: Sorry for typo i meant tried that one as well using . I will ask my DBA to create an index on this filed, does it have to clustered or non-clustered?

Comment: @user2158642 hopefully your only option is non-clustered because the table should already have a clustered index. Make sure you mention that the index should probably cover your query. Or maybe you should ask your DBA to write the query and he/she will be able to cater to the index strategy on his/her own (or point them to this thread).

Comment: my bad this column is actually indexed, one thing i dont get is when i input the value as '2013-08-01' it runs so fast, but when i say DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0); it bombs

Comment: @user2158642 one more time: we can only tell what "bombs" means if you collect the *actual execution plans* in both cases, and show them to us. Otherwise we can't really help you except throw potential solutions in your general direction. Do you want specific help, or generic help?

Comment: @user2158642 did you try using the options explained on this answer?

Comment: never ran explain plan in query studio, is there anything specific command i can use to run the explain plan?

Comment: I did try all the options mentioned above, i also used cast(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) + 1 - datepart(day, getdate()) as date)

Comment: Update cast(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) + 1 - datepart(day, getdate()) as date) works!!!.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am as confused as you (if not more), I also thought `GETDATE()` while not deterministic, is still essentially a constant, so is not optimised differently to a literal (unless there is already cached plan for that specific literal)?

Comment: oh yes, i just tweaked so i get 3 months back as per req :)

Comment: @user2158642 Yes, that is the point. If you had used 3 months earlier on your original query, you would've probably also "fixed" your issue. It didn't have to do with rewriting the way you were calculating the date, it has to do with changing the date

Comment: @user2158642 cast(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) + 1 - datepart(day, getdate()) as date)  will fail at the end of some months. Instead use cast(dateadd(month, -3, GETDATE() + 1 - datepart(day, getdate())) as date)