# How to get 00:00:00 in datetime, for First of Month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I wrote a query to obtain First of month,

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())-1), GETDATE()) as First_Of_Month;
```

for which i do get the appropriate output, but my time stamp shows the current time.

Here's what I am doing in the query, hope i make sense.

using `datepart` i calculated the no. of days (int) between the 1st and today (27-1 =26) 
Then using `dateadd` function, i added "-datepart" to get the first of the month.

This is just changing the date, what should i look at or read about in order to change the time. I am assuming that it would have something to do with 19000101

Comment: Thank you Mark for editing it the right way. :)

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Also what will you be using this for?

Comment: @AaronBertrand : Am using SS-2008R2

Comment: Great, please always questions with a version so people don't have to guess. The answer can matter.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : Another useful tip from you. 
Am new to forum so do forgive my silly mistakes.

Comment: don't even think about it, we all started on this site at one point...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For SQL Server 2012** (thanks adrift and i-one)

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@now, -1));

-- or

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@now), MONTH(@now), 1);
```

**For SQL Server 2008+**

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

-- This shorthand works:

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @now+1-DAY(@now));

-- But I prefer to be more explicit, instead of relying on
-- shorthand date math (which doesn't work in all scenarios):

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@now), @now));
```

**For SQL Server 2005**

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()),0);
```

A caveat if you're using this SQL Server 2005 method: you need to be careful about using expressions involving `DATEDIFF` in queries. [SQL Server can transpose the arguments and lead to horrible estimates](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/630583/incorrect-estimate-with-condition-that-includes-datediff) - [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241977/query-runs-slow-with-date-expression-but-fast-with-string-literal/). It might actually be safer to take the slightly less efficient string approach:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112) + '01');
```

Comment: +1, just for fun `DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1))` for 2012+?

Comment: @adrift ok, I'll add it, though I will confess I am not a huge fan of that function. `BOMONTH()` would have been far more useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY, - (DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())-1), GETDATE()),120)+' 00:00:00' as First_Of_Month;
```

Comment: Let me check if i got this right, 
1) The first of month is converted to the format code of 120,
2) Why the  +'00:00:00' ? Is this just to add "space 00:00:00" ?

Answer (score 1):

Just the date

```
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

So for a month it is:

```
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0,  GETDATE()), 0) AS FirstDatetimeOfMonthmm,
```

Comment: Depending on how it is used, [be very wary of `DATEDIFF` when comparing to a column](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/630583/incorrect-estimate-with-condition-that-includes-datediff).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as First_Of_Month;
```

Comment: Which give me todays date with time stamp 00:00:00, thanks for this. :)
And now i need to look for a way to make it, so that i get 1st of month.

Comment: Please don't promote the use of shorthand. You may have memorized that M is month, but are you ever surprised by, say, `SELECT DATEPART(Y, GETDATE());` or `SELECT DATEPART(W, GETDATE());`? It's not a lot of effort to type `MONTH` and it makes your code self-document.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to cast the result to date:

```
SELECT cast(DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())-1), GETDATE()) as date) as First_Of_Month
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative:

```
SELECT cast(
    cast(datepart(yyyy, getdate()) as varchar)
  + '-'
  + cast(datepart(mm, getdate()) as varchar) + '-01 00:00:00'
as datetime)
```

Build up the date from year/month components, then tack on the 1st and midnight.

Answer (score 0):

***Try following code:***

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) AS StartDateTime,
DATEADD(ms, -3,  CAST(CONVERT(date, DATEADD (DAY,1,GETDATE())) AS varchar(10))) AS EndDateTime
```

***Result:***

| StartDateTime | EndDateTime |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-23 00:00:00.000 | 2022-05-23 23:59:59.997 |