# Ridiculously huge impact of comparison operator on query execution duration

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following views defined:

**dsplit_base** - a union of 4 queries each of which is a simple join between fact and mapping tables (contains call statistics); it consists of 201 columns

**calls_check** - a view derived from the dsplit_base meant to be used in data consistency check. Here is the definition:

```
SELECT a.Brand,
       a.[Call Center] ,
       c.date,
       c.weekday,
       COUNT(*) vol,
       cast((COUNT(*)-g.vol) AS real)/g.vol*100 vol_diff ,
       SUM(abncalls+acdcalls) calls ,
       CASE
           WHEN g.calls<>0 THEN cast((SUM(abncalls+acdcalls)-g.calls) AS real)/g.calls*100
           ELSE CASE
                    WHEN SUM(abncalls+acdcalls)<>0 THEN 100
                    ELSE 0
                END
       END calls_diff
FROM dsplit_base a
JOIN calendar c ON a.ROW_DATE=c.date
JOIN
  ( SELECT t.Brand,
           t.[Call Center],
           c.weekday,
           avg(cast(vol AS bigint)) vol,
           AVG(cast(calls AS bigint)) calls
   FROM
     ( SELECT Brand,
              [Call Center], row_date, COUNT(*) vol, SUM(abncalls+acdcalls) calls from dsplit_base group by ROW_DATE, [Call Center],
              Brand ) t
   JOIN calendar c ON t.row_date=c.date
   GROUP BY c.weekday,
            t.[Call Center],
            t.Brand) g ON c.weekday=g.weekday
AND a.Brand=g.Brand
AND a.[Call Center]=g.[Call Center]
GROUP BY c.date,
         c.weekday,
         g.vol,
         g.calls,
         a.[Call Center],
         a.Brand
```

The following query yields around 16000 rows in 1-3 seconds:

```
    select * from calls_check

Brand   Call Center date    weekday     vol vol_diff    calls   calls_diff
LMN Munich      2008-01-24  Thursday    3   -25     470 8.796296
LMN Munich      2008-04-26  Saturday    3   0       352 51.72414
...
```

Now the actual problem I encountered is when I tried to pull out results for limited period of time. By adding where clause as follows the query will not finish (surely not in ~10 minutes):

```
    select * from calls_check
    where date >= DATEADD(d, -8, sysdatetime())
```

And, what is maybe even weirder, this query executes successfully in a second!

```
    select * from calls_check
    where date < DATEADD(d, -8, sysdatetime())
```

Can anybody tell why comparison operator in where clause makes such a difference? Why **<** seems to very efficiently slice the result set while  **>** or **=** makes the query unresponsive?

---

### Some additional info:

The dsplit_base view consists of 4 tables union (with joins). Here are their row counts:

dsplit_DE    - 2521

dsplit_WNS   - 7243

dsplit_US    - 121451

partners     - 377841 (166043)

actual 'partners' table row count is 166043 because in the view it takes rows on this condition:

```
from partners p join splitdim s 
ON p.[Skill Name]=s.SPLITNAME and (p.Date>=s.[start_date] or s.[start_date] is null) and (p.DATE<=s.[end_date] or s.[end_date] is null)
where s.[Call center] IN ('Sitel', 'TRX', 'Sellbytel') 
OR (s.[Call center]='WNS' and p.Date<(select MIN(row_Date) from dsplit_WNS))
OR (s.[Call Center]='Munich' and (p.Date<'2012-06-29' or p.Date between '2012-08-01' and '2012-08-27'))
```

I experimented with modified view definition and found out that:

having the view with dsplit_DE and/or dsplit_WNS only both queries work pretty fast (1-2 seconds)

with partners only the '>=' query took ~30s
; with dsplit_US only it took ~60s

here is the actual execution plan of the latter [EXEC PLAN](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4L60aY5Y92GVkY5SFRUWG5SQzA)

The last two table are much bigger than others yet with a few hundred thousands of records it should not take so long. What causes the difference in execution time depenending on '<'  or '>' operator used in where clause?

Comment: Have you checked/compared the execution plans? See for instance: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Comment: It could very well be this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241977/query-runs-slow-with-date-expression-but-fast-with-string-literal/18242413#18242413

Comment: what is the total row count of calls_check ? try running select   count(*) from calls_check
    where date >= DATEADD(d, -8, sysdatetime()) and see how long that takes.

Comment: The subquery g always returns 7 rows, one for each weekday, correct? . That query needs all rows of dsplit_base without restrictions. Depending on the execution plan, that query could be executed many times instead of just once. You might want to consider caching that part of the query.

Comment: They are selecting completely opposite ranges. Why would you expect that they would perform the same? Are both ranges in fact the same size in your data?

Comment: Alright. select count(*) from calls_check yields 16166 rows in a few seconds; select count(*) from calls_check where date < DATEADD(d, -8, sysdatetime()) yields  16071. Now select count(*) from calls_check where date >= DATEADD(d, -8, sysdatetime()) took 12 min 58 sec to return 95.

Comment: So are the execution plans basically the same or are they different? If they are different try updating statistics. If they are the same maybe it is just that because `where date >= DATEADD(d, -8, sysdatetime())` covers more recent rows you are getting blocked by concurrent modifications.

Comment: Update the question and for the third time compare the execution plans.

Comment: I am looking for a site where I could share the execution plan files...

Comment: here they are: [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4L60aY5Y92GaVg4MEJVWVh2cUU&usp=sharing#list)

Comment: @Maju - They are fairly large plans and I didn't have time to look at them in any detail but if you update the stats on `[SCC_MI_Calls].[dbo].[dsplit_US].[ROW_DATE]` does that help?

Comment: @MartinSmith interesting point - will check tomorrow when I am back at work

Comment: @Maju - There is a common issue with ascending date columns that the statistics don't get updated frequently enough. I did notice that the estimates for this join were wrong but I can't say whether that is the only issue in that plan.

Comment: I updated statistics, then rebuilt all indexes on related tables, updated stats again and executed the ">=" query - it took 05:52 so half the time of previous trials. Here is the plan: [LINK](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4L60aY5Y92GN3NFSEk1M1FOWEk/edit?usp=sharing)

But it is still 6 minutes vs 3 seconds so there is a fundamental problem affecting the query. Maybe indexes structure?

Comment: @MartinSmith - I appreciate your help; if you have a minute take a look at my "additional info" in the main question and another execution plan for dsplit_US only ([EXEC PLAN](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4L60aY5Y92GVkY5SFRUWG5SQzA))

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know **<** and **>=** are different
For example 
**What value of X if x <4 it would be Less than 4 or 3,2,1...** meanwhile **What value of X if x >=4 it would be 4,5,6.....**
meaning to say they yield different result, and maybe the reason behind is that

```
     select * from calls_check
where date < DATEADD(d, -8, sysdatetime())
```

Retrieves only minimal Data

While

```
 select * from calls_check
    where date >= DATEADD(d, -8, sysdatetime())
```

Retrieves a lot of data that's why it needs a lot of time to retrieve it

And also you need to be very careful when comparing dates, the should be both in `datetime` not in `string` it will cause bugs and it will not yield the expected result

Hope this helps thanks :)

Comment: As to how many rows are returned in case of the two operators:
<  - 16071
>= - 95

the query without where caluse returns 16166 rows very quickly

Comment: @Maju it is because without where clause SQL doesnt need to test it one by one if it shoots in your condition, having where cluase tests its data adding to the amount of time it can generate a query, Try using indexing it will help you alot.

Comment: All 4 underlying tables have indexes inluding date (row_date)
My question is why '<' works in the clause while '>' does not -  or more precisely takes hundreds times longer.

Comment: here they are: [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4L60aY5Y92GaVg4MEJVWVh2cUU&usp=sharing#list)