# Huge impact of >= operator in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have already asked virtually the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483701/ridiculously-huge-impact-of-comparison-operator-on-query-execution-duration) but it has not been answered satisfactory and I just came around a similar situation.

```
select r.order_number, cl.COMMANDE, m.[order #]
from [Offline RN General] r 
left join mcdb_summary m ON r.order_number=m.[order #]
left join coclico cl ON cl.ORDER_ID=r.order_number
where r.[order_number] is not null and r.GroupID=358472  and converted='yes' and r.[Booking Date]>='20140401'
```

so the last condition (r.[Booking Date]**>=**'20140401') causes the query to take at least 40 seconds to complete while without that one condition or - bizarrely - or if it is r.[Booking Date]**<**'20140401' it only takes up to 2 seconds.
[image: greater or equal]
[image: less than]

In the first case apparently the most impact is made by [mcdb_summary].[suggested2] index scan - it was previously suggested by ssms - and here is its definition:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [suggested2] ON [dbo].[mcdb_summary] 
(
    [cancelled] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [order #],
[Product_Name]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Can someone point me to a possible cause and resolution to the issue?

Comment: Could you share the XML execution plan? Right-click the background on graphic representation of exec plan and from the popup menu choose "Save Execution Plan As..." and save it to a file with sqlplan extension. It's a plain XML file, you can open it in Notepad, sqlplan extension simply associates it with SSMS. Then upload it to dropbox, sky/onedrive or similar and share. Otherwise we can only guess what is happening.

Comment: My guess is that the slowdown comes from the nested loops. Try to update statistics and maybe force some HASH JOIN and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to try:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [Offline RN General];
```

Statistics provide info about data distribution (e.g. how many rows are for date X, how many for date Y, etc) and this helps query engine to take "cost-based" decisions: perform a index seek rather than an index scan, etc.

You can see those statististics by running a simple [SQL query](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/statistics-info-about-index):

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('<tablename>', '<indexname>');
```

You can read more about when statistics [are updated](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/when-update-statistics-flag-2371).

Comment: hmm, since [Offline RN General] is a view I executed the command on the underlying table (UPDATE STATISTICS Offline_RN;) and it did the trick!
I will do some tests and flag your answer as right then. Why statistics of one table has such a big impact on queries? I though I got my indexes wrong. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Alright, here is the execution plan after updating stats
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4L60aY5Y92GSzEyaGY5MmZOaTg/edit?usp=sharing
I hust do not understand why I had to manually  execute update while sp_autostats shows the table's autostats are ON

Comment: Check the link in the response for details. Simple said, table statistics changes: 
• When a table has fewer than 500 rows and is increased by 500 or more rows
• When a table has more than 500 rows and is increased by 500 rows + 20 percent of the number of rows

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing an index, I would ensure all the keys possible are in good order to optimize the query on your "R" table.

```
table                 index
[Offline RN General]  ( groupID, converted, order_number, [booking date]  )
mcdb_summary          ( [order #] )
coclico               ( order_id, commande )
```

Also, confirmation of all columns (converted) should be qualified to the table... I can only GUESS that converted is in the Offline RN General table.