# SQL Server - Shows dates within the current month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm just new to sql server query. I have a column named duedate. I want to filter duedate data within the current month.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE duedate = within current month only
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use a range query rather than wrapping the column in a function call so that an index may be used.

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE1
WHERE  duedate >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
       AND duedate < DATEADD(month, 1 + DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Comment: This query uses Index on column.

Comment: But don't forget about [this issue](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/datediff-bug) which you first smartened me up about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18242413/61305).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Good point, shame they didn't mention version of SQL Server. The workaround on the linked question is 2008+.