# Efficient SQL view with automatic date range based on Getdate

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am trying to create a view that automatically pulls data from the last twelve months (starting from the end of the last month.)

When I run this with a where clause like the following :

```
WHERE Visit_Date between 'Dec 1 2012' and 'Dec 1 2013'
```

It will run in a ~1min.

I have some calculations that will automatically create those dates. But when I use them in the where clause the query is still running after 15 minutes.

```
WHERE Visit_Date between DATEADD(mm,-12,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,12,GETDATE()),0))
                 and Dateadd(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,12,GETDATE()),0))
```

The query is running on a table with 50+ million records. I am sure there this is a more efficient way to do this. I am guessing what is happening is its running through the Getdate() calculations for every row, which is obviously not ideal.

Any suggestions?
Please keep in mind that I am creating a view, and I don't usually write stored procedures or dynamic SQL.

Comment: Do you have an index on Visit_Date Column ??

Comment: 1) I hope you have a `DATE` column or a [SMALL]DATETIME column with '00:00:00.000' as time. 2) This expression `Dateadd(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,12,GETDATE()),0))` returns  the last day of the previous month (me: `2013-11-30 00:00:00.000`) and not the first day of the current month (me: `'Dec 1 2013'`) 3) You should publish the execution plans for both queries.

Comment: Also if you are using SQL Server 2012 you can create a ColumnStore Index, It really does some wonders

Comment: This may have to do with [a bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/630583/incorrect-estimate-with-condition-that-includes-datediff "Incorrect estimate with condition that includes > datediff") that is discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241977/query-runs-slow-with-date-expression-but-fast-with-string-literal "Query runs slow with date expression, but fast with string literal").

Answer (score 2):

I think @Andriy is probably right ([I've also blogged about it](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/datediff-bug)) that this is due to a cardinality estimation bug (the dates are reversed when making estimates). You can see more details in [KB #2481274](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2481274), [Connect #630583](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/630583/incorrect-estimate-with-condition-that-includes-datediff) and the question @Andriy pointed out:

[Query runs slow with date expression, but fast with string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241977/query-runs-slow-with-date-expression-but-fast-with-string-literal)

For something you only change once a month, I think you could consider creating a job that alters the view at the beginning of every month, hard-coding the date range into the view. This might not be a terrible alternative to enabling [trace flag 4199](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974006), which may or may not be a permanent fix, and may or may not cause other issues if you turn it on globally (as opposed to just for the session that runs this query - again no guarantee it will always make this fast). Here is the kind of process I am thinking about:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AlterThatView
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @end DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE());

  DECLARE @start DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @end);

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'ALTER VIEW dbo.ViewName
    AS
      SELECT ...
      WHERE Visit_Date >= ''' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), @start, 112) + ''' 
        AND Visit_Date <  ''' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), @end,   112) + ''';';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

Just create a job that runs, say, a minute after midnight on every 1st of the month, and calls this procedure. You may want to have the job to run a `SELECT` from the view once too.

Please [don't use BETWEEN for date range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) and [stop using lazy shorthand for dateparts](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I've managed to implement your SPROC solution. I actually have several related views with this problem. Would I be able to alter them all in one SPROC? Could I just declare a second @SQL_2?

Comment: @JKitz yes, you could alter them all in one procedure (it is not a "SPROC") - but you don't need multiple variables. Just set a new `ALTER` command to `@sql` and execute it each time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can return rows in < 1 minute in a table with 50M+ rows, I'm guessing you have an index on the Visit_Date column. In your first query, the SQL query plan generator does a seek on the index because it has a rough idea of how many rows will be returned, because it knows the date boundaries. It then makes a determination that an index seek on the index is the best plan of action.

In your second query, it doesn't know, or doesn't know as accurately how many rows might be returned, so it is probably deciding to do an index or table scan instead of a seek.

One option you could consider is using an Index Hint on the query. If this is not production code and just, perhaps, an ad-hoc query you perform on occasion, an index hint is safe. The problem is that if the index gets dropped, or the name changes, the query will fail. So keep that in mind.

Something else to keep in mind is that if you provide an index hint, SQL Server will use that index. If the span of time between your start and end date is such that a larger percentage of your table gets returned, a seek may not be as efficient as a scan (which is why a scan is sometimes selected by SQL Server).

Your best friend here is analyzing the estimated query plan that is generated. You can get this in SSMS. I would experiment with a few approaches until you can get an index seek (not a scan) being performed on your query.