# Speed up query containing convert

Tags: sql, sql-server

does someone know how to speed up following query:

```
select count (*)

from table

where column1 between DATEADD(day, -90,  convert(date, getdate())) AND getdate() 

and column2 is not null
```

This query takes 20 sec. for 8.000 rows

I think/know the bottleneck is the conversion, but it is necessary...

Comment: Google around the topic -  Sargable argument, should be an interesting read. Have fun

Comment: @mxix this way of calculating the dates should be sargable

Comment: @t-clausen.dk indeed, and that is why the conversion is not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely to be an index issue.

There is a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/630583/incorrect-estimate-with-condition-that-includes-datediff) in sqlserver-2008. It should be fixed in newer versions of sqlserver

Try this instead:

```
declare @from datetime = DATEADD(day, -90,  convert(date, getdate()))
declare @to datetime = getdate() 

select count (*)
from table
where column1 between @from and @to 
and column2 is not null
```

You can read about a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241977/query-runs-slow-with-date-expression-but-fast-with-string-literal/18242413#18242413)

Answer (score 2):

Your query is fine.  The conversions are on constants, rather than on the column.  Instead, you need an index.  This will probably help:

```
create index idx_table_column1_column2 on table(column1, column2);
```

This is a covering index, so only the index will be used to satisfy the query.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that column1 and WHERE clause condition datatypes are compatible or not.
Also try to create the index on columns when necessary, but there is always maintenance over head for 
indexes.

Thanks.