# Between clause for sql query(SQL server) not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a problem where i have a simple **sql** query as displayed below:

```
Select 
    Ah_editime as todaysdate,
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(GETDATE()) - 1), GETDATE()), 103)) AS monthstartdate,
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 103)) AS monthcurrentdate
from 
    Transaction
where 
    Ah_editime BETWEEN (CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(GETDATE()) - 1), GETDATE()), 103)) 
               AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 103))
```

I want to display result only for current month to till date. But the problem that I face is I get the values from past month as well which creates issues. I have a report that displays the values.

[image: report]

Here if you see I am getting all the values but I want for the current month only.

P.S : Can that be the format issue? `todaysdate` that is getting displayed which is my actual value.

Comment: sample data to test would be helpful.

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi : i have added the image.

Comment: Can you format todaysdate to some correct date format?

Comment: It seems your result looks correct to me...the dates are in DDMMYYYY format, which is 1st February 2015 to 10th February 2015.

Comment: or else use the following date format in your query to see date in MMDDYYYY. `BETWEEN (CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()),101)) 
AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),101))`

Comment: @RaoY: this is not what i am expecting. the result(todaysdate) i need should be between current month start date i.e 1 feb and current date 10feb. But this is not working.

Comment: @RaoY: Thanks Rao, it worked. If you post this as answer i will accecpt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` format should be modified as below in your query. Instead of 103 use 101.

```
BETWEEN (CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()),101)) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),101))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520803/711861) post, what about following query :

```
DECLARE @monthStartDate AS DATE 
DECLARE @monthCurrentDate AS DATE
SELECT  @monthStartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
SELECT  @monthCurrentDate = GETDATE()

SELECT  CAST(Ah_editime AS DATE) AS todaysdate ,
        @monthStartDate AS MonthStartDate ,
        @monthCurrentDate AS MonthCurrentDate
FROM    [Transaction]
WHERE   Ah_editime BETWEEN @monthStartDate AND     @monthCurrentDate
```