# How to see if date is in current month SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a `Ticket_Date` column that is in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`

I want to check if the `Ticket_date` is in the current month.

So far I have :

```
 Ticket_date >= '2015-04-01' and Ticket_date < '2015-04-30'
```

but I need it to work with the current month rather then hardcoded

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 YEAR(Ticket_date) = YEAR(getdate()) and 
MONTH(Ticket_date) = MONTH(getdate())
```

but i would also save current date in variable to guarantee what result of `getdate()` doesn't change when executing long query at midnight

```
declare @today datetime = getdate()
...
 YEAR(Ticket_date) = YEAR(@today) and 
MONTH(Ticket_date) = MONTH(@today)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
MONTH(Ticket_date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(Ticket_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
where ticket_date >= cast(getdate() - day(getdate) + 1 as date) and
      ticket_date < dateadd(month, 1, cast(getdate() - day(getdate) + 1 as date) )
```

This formulation has no functions on `ticket_date`, so SQL Server can use an index on the column, if appropriate.

Comment: when i trigger this in `2019-01-22` it will generate condition `>= '2019-01-01' and < '2019-02-01'` which will returns also records for January month, not only February as current month. But you have good point with the index usage.

Comment: @Muflix . . . The question is:  "I want to check if the Ticket_date is in the current month."  This query is the most efficient way to achieve that result.

Comment: you are right. It will not return February which was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What about (Server 2008 R2+)

```
-- first day of current month
Ticket_date  >= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
-- last day of current month 
and Ticket_date <= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
```

More examples here
[How can I select the first day of a month in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql)

- Why do you omit the `=` in `Ticket_date < '2015-04-30'` ?