# how to convert date passed in by user to the first of every month for the year that was passed in in SSRS?

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services

User inputs a date.

Based on this date, I have to get the first day of each month of the year in this date.

Example:

User input: 2/1/2014

From that, I need an expression that will get me -

```
1/1/2014
3/1/2014
4/1/2014
```

and so on.

I need the expression for each of the dates (not all together).

Basically if someone can help me figure out how to get one of the dates, I can do the rest.

EDIT - I got it guys. Sorry I wasn't clear enough.

```
=CDate("1/1/" + Year(Now).ToString)
=CDate("2/1/" + Year(Now).ToString)
=CDate("3/1/" + Year(Now).ToString)
```

and so on.

Comment: This seems like a very strange way to go about this.  Can't you just match on the month and day of the inputted year in SQL?  Why is this being done in SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select to_char( hire_date, 'dd-mm-yy') from employees where to_char(hire_date,'dd')='&dd';

if your using sql use this it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0) AS StartOfMonth
```

Where `@mydate` is your user inputted date, to get the first day of the month they passed in.

For more info, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql).

Comment: guys, im trying to do this in SSRS and not SQL... I need a way to modify the date that is passed in so that it gives me the dates I want... again, not all at the same time.