# Dates between 18 and 9 months ago but from beginning to end of relevant months

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that I thought I had cracked to return all records where the start date is between 18 and 9 months ago but I want all of the records for the month 18 months ago from the 1st of the month and all of the records for the month 9 months ago to the end of the month as well as the records in between.
At the moment my WHERE clause contains:

```
WHERE startdate BETWEEN 
DATEADD(DAY, - (DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())) - 18), DATEADD(MONTH, - 18, GETDATE())) 
AND DATEADD(DAY, - (DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())) - 9), DATEADD(MONTH, - 9, GETDATE())
```

But it is pulling all records where start date is between 18 and 9 months ago to the exact date today and is not going back to the start of the month or completing the end month.  Please could you advise where I have gone wrong.  I am sure it is something really simple but I have gone bracket blind now I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateAdd` and `DateDiff` to get the first day of the month, like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520803/3094533).

From this it's fairly simple to do something like this:

```
WHERE StartDate >= DATEADD(month, -18, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
AND StartDate < DATEADD(month, -8, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use new [SQL EMONTH() end of month function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/end-of-month-eomonth-function-in-sql-server-2012.aspx)

For the first of month, you can add 1 day to the previous month's end of month

Comment: Downvote reason: `EOMONTH()` was introduced in sql server 2012. the OP is asking about Sql server 2008 r2. there is no `EOMONTH()` in this version.