# Add a number (13) to the month and change the day to the 1st of that month

Tags: sql-server

I am sure this one is simple but I am having a difficult time figuring it out. I am trying to add 13 months to a date and that resulting month needs to default to the 1st day of the month.

```
Example:
Date: 1/25/2016
Query results: 2/1/2017
```

Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT Dateadd(month,13,getdate())
```

Comment: here is an example of how to get the first day of month.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL 2012+

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 12))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you. Just replace GETDATE() with your date.

```
select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dateadd(month, 13, GETDATE())), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just construct the date from the constituent parts, by adding 1 year + 1 month and forcing the day part to 1 (and taking care of the special case of month = 12), like this:

```
select DATEFROMPARTS (
    year(getdate()) + case when month(getdate()) = 12 then 2 else 1 end, 
    case when month(getdate()) = 12 then 1 else month(getdate()) + 1 end, 
    1 
)
```