# Syntax issue determine 1 day of month based on calculation

Tags: sql-server

I disagree - I am looking for the correct syntax to change the where clause to first return the results of the first part of the where clause then return the first of the month of that date result.  Need help with the correct syntax.

thanks,

K

```
-- DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Modify the Where statement

> Blockquote

CAST([PKDate] AS DATE) > CAST(GETDATE() - 91 AS DATE)

> Blockquote

to always reflect the first day of the month for the results of the 91 day calculation - ie. if the date of 91 days back = 3/10/2016, then the actual date should be 3/1/2016

```
SELECT [PKDate]
, [calendar_MONTH] as MthNo
, [is_weekend]
, [is_workday]
, Day(EOMONTH([PKDate])) as DaysinMth
FROM [calendar].[dbo].[days]
WHERE   CAST([PKDate] AS DATE) > CAST(GETDATE() - 91 AS DATE)
AND CAST([PKDate] AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() - 1 AS DATE)
GROUP BY [PKDate], calendar_MONTH
, is_weekend
, [is_workday]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select the first day of a month in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql)

Comment: I disagree, my question is how do I format the where clause to pass the correct first of the month date on the results of the 91 days back calculation?

Comment: And you don't see how being able to get the first day of the month for the date 91 days ago would solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might even be simpler...

```
DATEADD(DAY, -91, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I got it!!!

```
SELECT [PKDate]
, a.[calendar_month] as MthNo
, [is_weekend]
, [is_workday]
, Day(EOMONTH([PKDate])) as DaysinMth
, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, CAST(GETDATE() - 91 AS DATE)), 0) as AdjDate
FROM [calendar].[dbo].[days] a
WHERE   CAST([PKDate] AS DATE) > DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, CAST(GETDATE() - 91 AS DATE)), 0)
    AND CAST([PKDate] AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() - 1 AS DATE)
GROUP BY [PKDate]
    ,   a.calendar_MONTH
    ,   is_weekend
    ,   [is_workday]
```