# Capture the first of the current month to current day date range in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am selecting fields like client id, name, and service date. I am trying to write in my where clause, that every day I run my query it will capture a date range of the first of the current month to the current day.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql The rest should be easy. Hint `Date between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0) and @mydate`

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to compare the month and the year:

```
where year(col) = year(getdate()) and
      month(col) = month(getdate()) and
      day(col) <= day(getdate())  -- this is optional, if there is no future data
```

Another method would be to compare to the beginning of the month.  I would approach this as:

```
where col >= cast(dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate), getdate()) as date)
```

(This assumes there is no future data in the table.)

or, better yet:

```
where col >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select * 
    From YourTable 
    where SomeDateField bewteen cast(DateAdd(DD,-Day(GetDate())+1,GetDate()) as Date)  and cast(getDate() as Date)
      and ...
```

> Edit:  I used the BETWEEN to trap possible future date/scheduled events