# SQL TO_CHAR TO_NUMBER TO_DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01481

I have the following expression

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dab.SNAPSHOT_DAY,'YYYYMMDD'),'MM') >=
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD'),'MM') -1

'{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}' returns the date of when the data was captured.
```

I get the following error:

> ORA-01481:invalid number format model

Columns are coherent in terms of data types.
    `dab.SNAPSHOT_DAY` is `{DATE} 2016-07-24 00:00:00.0`

Would you have any hint of what could be happening?

What I am trying to do is to get results from current and past month. That is why I want to transform both dates to MONTH (MM) and then substract 1. E.g.:

```
Snapshot_day = 05/JUN/2016 --> 06
RUN_DATE = 27/JUL/2016 --> 07
Comparing them: 06 >= 07 - 1 TRUE
```

Thank you all!

Comment: What is the date type of column `SNAPSHOT_DAY`?

Comment: `TO_DATE(dab.SNAPSHOT_DAY,'YYYYMMDD')` is totally senseless if `snapshot_day` is already a `date` column.

Comment: Rather than trying to fix this, you may be better off saying in plain English what the inputs are and what the desired result is. In any case comparing dates AFTER you transform them into strings is wrong, and it's not clear how you plan to subtract 1 from a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answers
I have added more info to the question so that it is clearer to understand.
As indicated in a below question, how could I do to verify the year as well? (i.e. January 2016 against December 2015)
thanks!

Comment: @alexparq - did it solve your question?

Comment: It worked perfectly but I tried to finalize it by removing the days of the current week, arriving to this expression below
dagm.SNAPSHOT_DAY BETWEEN TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_DD/MM/YYYY}','DD/MM/YYYY'),-1),'WW') AND TRUNC(TO_DATE('RUN_DATE_DD/MM/YYYY','DD/MM/YYYY'),'WW')
The thing is... it doesn't work. I have been reading on trunc statement and between, but I can't figure out why it is not working...

Comment: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Comment: @alexparq - This question was solved so please consider on marking it as solved. For a new error you receive, if you can't solve it, open a separate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `trunc` to get that specific part of the date that you want

```
where trunc(dab.SNAPSHOT_DAY,'MM') >= 
    trunc(to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD'),'MM') -1
```

But I think a better solution will be to:

```
where snapshot_day >= add_months(to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD'),-1)
```

And if the `{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}` is actually a parameter from a type of date:

```
where snapshot_day >= add_months(run_date),-1)
```

Comment: That won't throw an ORA-01481 though; the MM string will be implicitly converted to a number. I suspect your solution is close anyway - comparing just the month number, without the year, probably isn't right. The -1 might need to be before the trunc - but it isn't clear what's really needed.

Comment: I have provided further information above that will make my issue clearer
Thanks a lot for your support and education!

Comment: @alexparq - can you check now?

Comment: hi Gilad
It looks like it is working ( I will confirm it shortly ) but I have another question to complete what I want:
If I want to make sure I get data for the whole previous month, would this modification work?
    dab.SNAPSHOT_DAY >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD'),-1),'MM')

Comment: @alexparq - for that other question check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql)