# Get value for the first date in month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have weekly data of each product stock. I want to group it by year-month and get the first value of each month. In other words, I want to get the opening stock of each month, regardless the day of the month.

```
+------------+---------+
|   MyDate   | MyValue |
+------------+---------+
| 2018-01-06 |       2 |*
| 2018-01-13 |       7 |
| 2018-01-20 |       5 |
| 2018-01-27 |       2 |
| 2018-02-03 |       3 |*
| 2018-02-10 |      10 |
| 2018-02-17 |       6 |
| 2018-02-24 |       4 |
| 2018-03-03 |       7 |*
| 2018-03-10 |       5 |
| 2018-03-17 |       3 |
| 2018-03-24 |       4 |
| 2018-03-31 |       6 |
+------------+---------+
```

Desired results:

```
+----------------+---------+
| FirstDayOfMonth| MyValue |
+----------------+---------+
| 2018-01-01     |       2 |
| 2018-02-01     |       3 |
| 2018-03-01     |       7 |
+----------------+---------+
```

I thought this might work, but it ain't.

```
select 
    [product],
    datefromparts(year([MyDate]), month([MyDate]), 1),
    FIRST_VALUE(MyValue) OVER (PARTITION BY [Product], YEAR([MyDate]), MONTH([MyDate]) ORDER BY [MyDate] ASC) AS MyValue
from 
    MyTable 
group by 
    [Product],
    YEAR([MyDate]), MONTH([MyDate])
```

**Edit**. Thank you. The accent in my question is not how to get the first day of the month. I know that there are different techniques for that.

The accent is how to get the FIRST value in month (the opening stock). If there is a chance to get the closing stock in one shot - it would be great. The answers based on `ROW_NUMBER` do not allow to get closing stock in one shot, would require two joins.

**Edit after accepting answer**
Please consider John Cappelletti's answer as an alternative to the accepted one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53559750/1903793

Comment: Possible dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql `SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GetDate()), 0) AS StartOfMonth`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need the `GROUP BY` if you have chosen the window function route:

```
SELECT Product, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(MyDate, -1)) AS Month, MyValue
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(MyDate, -1)) ORDER BY MyDate) AS rn
    FROM t
) AS x
WHERE rn = 1
```

**UPDATE**

To get the last row for the month just do a `UNION ALL <above query>` but change the order by clause to `ORDER BY MyDate DESC`. This will give you two rows per product-month.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply` & `eomonth` to find the last day of month & add one day :

```
select distinct dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(t1.mydate, -1)) as FistDayOfMonth, t1.myvalue
from table t cross apply
     ( select top (1) t1.mydate, t1.myvalue
       from table t1
       where t1.product = t.product and
             year(t1.MyDate) = year(t.MyDate) and month(t1.MyDate) = month(t.MyDate)
       order by t1.mydate
     ) t1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also use a rowNumber and  cte.

[DEMO](https://rextester.com/BPFU66044)

```
WITH CTE as (
SELECT '2018-01-06' myDate,        2 Myvalue UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-01-13',        7 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-01-20',        5 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-01-27',        2 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-02-03',        3 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-02-10',       10 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-02-17',        6 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-02-24',        4 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-03-03',        7 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-03-10',        5 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-03-17',        3 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-03-24',        4 UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-03-31',        6),

CTE2 as (SELECT *
              , Row_Number() over (partition by DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, MyDate), 0) order by myDate) RN   
         FROM CTE)

SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, MyDate), 0), MyValue 
FROM cte2 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Giving us:

```
+----+---------------------+---------+
|    |  (No column name)   | MyValue |
+----+---------------------+---------+
|  1 | 01.01.2018 00:00:00 |       2 |
|  2 | 01.02.2018 00:00:00 |       3 |
|  3 | 01.03.2018 00:00:00 |       7 |
+----+---------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option is using the WITH TIES, and then a little cheat for the date

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties 
       MyDate = convert(varchar(7),MyDate,120)+'-01'
      ,MyValue
 from  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By convert(varchar(7),MyDate,120) Order By MyDate)
```

**Returns**

```
MyDate      MyValue
2018-01-01  2
2018-02-01  3
2018-03-01  7
```

Comment: That is crazy elegant answer. Never seen WITH TIES before. Can you link to any docs how it works? Can't get the logic of your answer.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Thanks for the grin :).   You can find a bit more information  here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017  Full disclosure Salman's RN approach would be more performant on larger tables...   but I prefer my date portion