# How to add first day and last day of month in between query in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(price),0) as total FROM table1
WHERE table1.id= 33 AND start_time BETWEEN '2019-09-1' AND '2019-09-11'
```

This works fine. Now I want to `SUM` the data of a month so I tried to use the `between` feature and get first day and last day of the month.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(price),0) as total FROM table1 
WHERE table1.id = 33 AND start_time BETWEEN (SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 
'2019-09-15'), 0) AND '2019-09-11'
```

I used this [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520803/8612835)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Your code has SQL Server functions.

Comment: I'm using `MySql`

Comment: What is `month` supposed to be? Is it a column in the table?

Comment: Then how can I get `first day` of month from the date ?

Comment: @Barmar It might be the query looks like the same but my issue and query is different. :)

Comment: The first day of what month?

Comment: Right now the the date is static after that I'll make it dynamic. I have a date like `2019-10-15`. From this date I want to get first date and last date of the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `last_day()` function without any argument to get the last day of month, and `date_format(@mydate, '%Y-%m-01')` to get the first day of the month. So, use :

```
set @mydate='2019-09-15';

select ifnull(sum(price),0) as total 
  from table1 
 where id = 33 
   and start_time between date_format(@mydate, '%Y-%m-01') and last_day(@mydate);
```

Comment: Hey I just perform the same query. :)

Comment: nice coincidence :) @SachinShah

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the first day of the month by subtracting the day of the month and adding one day:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(price), 0) as total
FROM table1 
WHERE table1.id = 33 AND
      start_time >= date('2019-09-15') + interval (1 - day(date('2019-09-15'))) day and
      start_time < date('2019-09-15')
```

Comment: syntax to use near 'day and
      start_time < date('2019-09-15')