# Get the first day of the month in date column in sql without providing date

Tags: sql

I have a price column and a date column in an sql database which contains daily prices for the last 10 years. I want to be able get the price for the 1st of the month for each month in the table without providing a date.

All solutions so far have required me to provide a date such as this: [How can I select the first day of a month in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql)

I am fairly new to SQL and so am unsure of the code within the answer. Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The database is an internal SQL database so I'm am unsure what you mean.

Comment: _internal SQL database_ - how do you connect to the database to run queries (what tools do you use?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses simple filtering:

```
select t.*
from t
where extract(day from date) = 1;
```

Date functions are particularly database-dependent.  `EXTRACT()` is standard SQL, but many databases use `DAY()` to extract the day of the month from the date.

Comment: As a newbie, I'm unsure what the database-dependency is? Do you mean like structure? Also with the answer wouldn't I have to from the date?

Comment: @gerardcslabs . . . date/time functions depend on the database being used.