# Dynamic Where Clauses for Dates

Tags: sql, date, dynamic, where-clause

Right now my code works, but it is not dynamic. Below shows the sum of daily values from a daily table in January 2022 compared to the monthly value from the monthly table for January 2022.

I am trying to figure out how to code this so the daily totals compared to the monthly can be pulled at anytime and I won't have to change the dates in the WHERE clauses everytime.

```
SELECT 
b.LocationDescription AS 'Location'
,CONVERT(varchar, cm.RecordDate, 1) AS 'Month Date'
,DATENAME(month,cm.RecordDate) AS 'Month'
,SUM(cm.Production) AS 'Monthly Prod'
,d.total AS 'Daily Prod'
,SUM(cm.Production)-d.total AS 'Diff'
,(CASE WHEN d.total = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (SUM(cm.Production) - d.total)/d.total*100 END) AS 'Percent'

FROM CompletionMonthlyTb cm

INNER JOIN CompletionTb c ON cm.SystemID = c.SystemID 
INNER JOIN LocationTb as b ON c.LocationID = b.LocationSystemID

JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
    b.LocationDescription AS 'Location'
    ,sum(cd.[Production])  AS 'Total'    
           
    FROM [xxxxxxx].[dbo].[LocationTb] b

    JOIN xxxxxxxxx.dbo.CompletionTb c ON c.LocationID = b.LocationSystemID
    JOIN xxxxxxx.dbo.CompletionDailyTb cd ON cd.SystemID = c.SystemID

    WHERE cd.RecordDate BETWEEN '1-1-2022' AND '1-31-22'
    
    GROUP BY b.LocationDescription) AS d ON d.Location = b.LocationDescription

WHERE cm.RecordDate = '2022-01-01' 

GROUP BY b.LocationDescription, cm.RecordDate, d.total

ORDER BY cm.RecordDate, b.LocationDescription
```

RESULTS:

```
Location  Month Date  Month    Monthly Prod   Daily Prod   Diff     Percent
Alpha     01/01/22    January   27663         25584        2079       8
Beta      01/01/22    January   25503         26104       -600       -2
```

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69397311/4892466

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select the first day of a month in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql)

Comment: Already answered

Comment: @TroyTurley am I able to put these options in the where clause? Everything I see is written in the select