# Filter by date in SQL Server table from the first day three months ago

Tags: sql-server, date, ssms, truncate

I have a table with `applicationdate` as one of its columns. I need to filter up to the past 3 months and not just three months ago from today, that is, if today is `9/26/2022`, I would like to filter from `6/1/2022`, and not `6/26/2022`.

This code pulls the three months ago from today

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE applicationdate >= DATEADD(month, -3, applicationdate)
```

resulting to 6/26/2022. I am interested up to 6/1/2022

According to some googling, I can use `trunc()`, `datetrunc()` or `date_trunc()` to get the first day of the three months ago, but each of them throws a function error saying:

> 'function' is not a recognized built-in function name.

How can I filter to the first of three months ago?

Comment: Use a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) with a column IsFirstOfMonth. then you can join to the calendar table and filter based on the columns. or have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql

Comment: Those functions are Oracle functions not T-SQL functions. When googling about SQL Server always use `T-SQL` in your search terms.