# First date of any month in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am seeking to find first date of the month in the corresponding table:

[image]

So if i have 26/08/2011 August as date and 2 months to add, it becomes 26/10/2011. I need the first date of the resulting month- like 01/10/2011.

Can this be achieved in SQL?

Update : I could get the date of the month using
DATEADD(month,months_add, date)

Couldnt get to "beginning of month". Tried: [How can I select the first day of a month in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql)
But for me it throws the error: function pg_catalog.date_diff("unknown", integer, date) does not exist;

Comment: checkout the date functions of sql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html (first hit on google ;) ) Tell us what you tried so far and if there are still problems

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: *26/08/2011* In MySQL this is NOT correct date format.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using  date_add  for add two months and date_sub  for sub the days -1

```
set @my_date = "2017-06-15";
SELECT DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD(@my_date, INTERVAL 2 MONTH), 
       INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(@my_date)-1 DAY);
```

Comment: Wrong. `set @my_date = "2017-12-31";` => `'2018-01-29'`.

Comment: First truncate the date to the first of the month and then add the requested number of months

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT table.date,
       table.month_add,
       DATE_FORMAT(table.date + INTERVAL table.month_add MONTH, 
                   '%Y-%m-01') AS beginning_of_month
FROM table
```

Comment: doesnt work :(.

Comment: @user2458552 Provide source data which produces incorrect output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date is currently a `varchar` in `dd/MM/yyyy` format, you can use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert it to a `DATE` type column, then use `DATE_ADD` with your `months_add` column to dynamically add months then finally use `DATE_FORMAT` to display it back in a `01/MM/yyyy` format with the first day of the month.

```
SELECT 
  Date_Column, 
  Date_Months_Add, 
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(Date_Column, "%d/%m/%Y" ), INTERVAL Date_Months_Add MONTH), '01/%m/%Y') AS Date_Beginning
FROM sample
```

**Result:**

```
| Date_Column | Date_Months_Add | Date_Beginning  |
|-------------|-----------------|-----------------|
| 26/08/2011  | 2               | 01/10/2011      |
| 25/04/2011  | 1               | 01/05/2011      |
| 16/09/2022  | 3               | 01/12/2022      |
| 14/07/2022  | 4               | 01/11/2022      |
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/60XcrwAs).