# How to fetch the records from the SQL Server Database using loop

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, dateadd

I have an employee table, I need to fetch the details of employees based on course 1 joining date for the last 12 months from the specified month.

Table Design

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Field     | Type        |   
+-----------+-------------+    
| emp_name  | varchar(30) | 
| join_date | date        | 
| emp_id    | int(5)      | 
| c1_date   | date        | 
+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to show the output below. c1_date joining date for the last 12 months' employee details.

For example, today date is 7/1/2023

first month:

```
emp_id , emp_name , joining_date , c1_date
1         xxx        21-7-7         12-12-2022
2         yyy        22-2-1         1-12-2022
```

second month:

```
emp_id , emp_name , joining_date , c1_date
11         abc        21-7-7         12-11-2022
21         cde        22-2-1         1-11-2022
```

Like above last 12 months i want to generate, i have created a procedure for this requirement, but i am getting all records without c1_date -1, -2, -3..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StudentReport] 
    @FromDate datetime =null
AS 

DECLARE @count INT;
SET @count = -1;

WHILE @count>= -12
BEGIN
   SELECT *
    FROM [Student]
    WHERE [Group Type] ='AIS-140' AND
    [c1_date] BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, @count, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
   SET @count = @count - 1;
END;
```

Help me figure out where I am committing the mistake.

Comment: Pet Peeve ... ambiguous dates  I suspect the loop is not required and should probably be avoided.   A simple join to a calendar table or even an ad-hoc numbers table

Answer (score 0):

This does not work, because if e.g. `GETDATE()='2023/01/07'` then `DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())` is `'2022/12/07'`. So, you will not get the full months. See [How can I select the first day of a month in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql). And also, looping in SQL is generally not a good idea. See; [Optimizing SQL: Removing queries inside loops](https://codeutopia.net/blog/2010/10/07/optimizing-sql-removing-queries-inside-loops/).