# SQL 1st of the month to the end of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an @StartDate and @EndDate.

I need the @StartDate to be the day the query is ran(which will always be the first of the month) and the @EndDate to be exaclty at the end of the month no matter if the month is 30 or 31 days, etc.

Comment: must be a duplicate ....

Comment: Think about this, the enddate is always plus 1 month - 1 day

Comment: @Mitch, I did do a quick search around but bizarrely couldn't find anything. I'm as surprised as anyone that this question didn't already exist, unless my search powers are failing me! ;=)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051488/get-the-last-day-of-the-month-in-sql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520789/how-can-i-select-the-first-day-of-a-month-in-sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A worked example:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(m, 1, @StartDate)

SELECT @StartDate, @EndDate - 1
```

Basically you want to take the start date, add one month (that's what the [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) is doing), and then deduct one day.

The output from that query is:

```
StartOfMonth            EndOfMonth
----------------------- -----------------------
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 2010-01-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: If you wanted to use current date.
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)