# SQL Query to find the last day of the month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, date, datetime

I need to find the last day of a month in the following format:

```
"2013-05-31 00:00:00:000"
```

Anybody please help out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the last day of the month in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051488/get-the-last-day-of-the-month-in-sql)

Comment: @Satindersingh: He tagged `sql-server-2005`. `EOMONTH` is 2012 and above.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetLastDayOfMonth] 
(
    @Date DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @Date) + 1, 0))

END
```

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SELECT @date = '2013-05-31 15:04:10.027'

SELECT DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @date) + 1, 0))
```

**Output:**

```
-----------------------
2013-05-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Just remember that if you're using this in a between statement to get (for example) all records for a given month, this will exclude records from the last day. You may need to use the first day of the next month instead.

Answer (score 62):

I know this question was for SQL Server 2005, but I thought I'd mention- as of SQL 2012, there now is an `EOMONTH()` function that gets the last day of the month. To get it in the format specified by the original asker you'd have to cast to a `datetime`.

```
SELECT CAST(eomonth(GETDATE()) AS datetime)
```

Answer (score 18):

SQL Server 2012 introduces [the `eomonth` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx):

```
select eomonth('2013-05-31 00:00:00:000')
-->
2013-05-31
```

Comment: He tagged `sql-server-2005`. `EOMONTH` is 2012 and above

Answer (score 9):

```
declare @date datetime;
set @date = getdate(); -- or some date
select dateadd(month,1+datediff(month,0,@date),-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dateadd(month,1+datediff(month,0,getdate()),-1)
```

To check run:

```
print dateadd(month,1+datediff(month,0,@date),-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Snowflake (and likely other SQL engines), you can use [`LAST_DAY`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_day.html).

```sql
select to_date('2015-05-08T23:39:20.123-07:00') as "DATE",
       last_day("DATE", 'MONTH') as "LAST DAY OF MONTH";
```

Which returns:

```
DATE         LAST DAY OF MONTH
2015-05-08          2015-05-31
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))) AS lastDayOfMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the last date of the month is quite simple calculation -

1 - Find the total months count till today's date using DATEDIFF function -

```
Select DATEDIFF(MM,0,GETDATE())
```

*Output - 1374, If getdate() output is "2014-07-23 19:33:46.850"*

2 -Increment by 1 into total months count -

```
Select DATEDIFF(MM,0,GETDATE())+1
```

*Output - 1375, If getdate() output is "2014-07-23 19:33:46.850"*

3 - Get the first date of next month -

```
Select DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,GETDATE())+1,0)
```

*Output - '2014-08-01 00:00:00.000', If getdate() output is "2014-07-23 19:33:46.850"*

4 - Subtract by -1 into the first date of next month, which will return last date of the current month -

```
Select DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
```

*Output - '2014-07-31 00:00:00.000', If getdate() output is "2014-07-23 19:33:46.850"*

In the same manner of calculation we can achieve the -

1. Last date of next month
2. Last date of the previous month
   and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))),DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))
```

This works great in T-sql ..

Replace the `GETDATE()` of the query with your column name .

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @GivenDate datetime 
Declare @ResultDate datetime 
DEclare @EOMDate datetime 
Declare @Day int 
set @GivenDate=getdate() 
set @GivenDate= (dateadd(mm,1,@GivenDate)) 
set @Day =day(@GivenDate) 
set @ResultDate=dateadd(dd,-@Day+1,@GivenDate) 
select @EOMDate =dateadd(dd,-1 ,@ResultDate) 
select @EOMDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a different version of adding a month and subtracting a day for creating reports:

ex: StartofMonth is '2019-10-01'

`dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,StartofMonth))`

EndOfMonth will become '2019-10-31'

Comment: What if you want a date column in place of StartOfMonth ? How does your query work ?

Answer (score -1):

```
TO FIND 1ST and Last day of the Previous, Current and Next Month in Oracle SQL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT 
SYSDATE,
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2))+1 FDPM,
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1)) LDPM,
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1))+1 FDCM,
LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)LDCM,
LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)+1 FDNM,
LAST_DAY(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)+1) LDNM
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Wecome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding some explanation to your code. Thank you.

Comment: The question was tagged `sql-server`, an answer about Oracle is not helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @date date=getdate()
declare @st_date date,@end_dt date
set @st_date=convert(varchar(5),year(@date))+'-'+convert(varchar(5),month(@date))+'-01'
set @end_dt=DATEADD(day,-1, DATEADD(month,1,@st_date))
---------**************--------------
select @st_date as [START DATE],@end_dt AS [END DATE]
```

Answer (score -1):

select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-0, -1) LastDate

Answer (score -1):

An excelent approach by me. Regards

```
DECLARE @MAXDATE INT=(SELECT MAX(DATEPART(YEAR,ORDERDATE)) FROM Orders)
DECLARE @MINDATE INT=(SELECT MIN(DATEPART(YEAR,ORDERDATE)) FROM Orders)
DECLARE @HORA INT=(SELECT MIN( DATEPART(HOUR,ORDERDATE)) FROM ORDERS)
DECLARE @DIA INT = 28

SELECT Employees.EmployeeID , Orders. OrderID , OrderDate  FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Orders 
ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
Where  (DATEPART(YEAR,ORDERDATE)) >=@mindate and  (DATEPART(YEAR,ORDERDATE))<= @maxdate
and DATEPART(HOUR,ORDERDATE)=@HORA   and DATEPART(DAY,ORDERDATE) IN (30,31) OR DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEPART(DAY,ORDERDATE))=28 AND
DATEADD(MONTH,0,DATEPART(MONTH,ORDERDATE))=2
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```