# SQL IF statement to see if today is the end of the month

Tags: sql

Trying to see if today is the end of the month and if it is run the code, I am thinking to use EOMONTH and getdate but I'm not sure how.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150232/sql-how-to-tell-if-a-date-is-the-last-day-of-the-month   Try googling it frist next time <3

Comment: What DBMS do you use because every DBMS has it's own methods to calculate with dates

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS SQL Sever `GETDATE()` returns the current date and time, and `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` returns today's date in yyyy-mm-dd format without including the time. `EOMONTH()` returns type date so `EOMONTH(GETDATE())` returns the last day of the current month in yyyy-mm-dd format. Therefore if you're using a statement block:

```
IF CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) = EOMONTH(GETDATE())
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Today is the end of the month'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Today is not the end of the month'
END
```

And if you're just looking for a basic IF..ELSE without the statement block:

```
IF CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) = EOMONTH(GETDATE())
    PRINT 'Today is the end of the month'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Today is not the end of the month'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF(GETDATE() = EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'TODAY IS THE END OF MONTH' 
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'TODAY IS NOT THE END OF MONTH'
END
```

http://rextester.com/NAH54861