# SQL Server end of month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose there is one date in `int` format `20191229`, I want to find end of month and check if it's end of month is of 31 days or 30 days in SQL Server

Comment: Why are you storing dates as an `int`? You're should really be using the date and time data types; it's what they're for.

Comment: I will add from myself. `DATE` data type takes less disk space. It requires 3 bytes, while `INT` data type requires 4 bytes, `DATETIME` data type - 8 bytes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If your version of SQL Server does not have the `EOFMONTH` function the see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646585/sql-query-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month) answer. (Function was added in 2016)

Comment: `EOMONTH` is available in every **supported** version of SQL Server, @PeterSmith . I *think* it was added with th 2012, but it might have been 2008.

Comment: @Lamu. I checked the Microsoft documentation before posting the comment. It's definitely not in 2008R2 and the reference says not in 2014. Is there a definitive source as to when features were introduced.

Comment: It's definitely in 2012+ @PeterSmith as the office still has 2012 instances and I use it. Quick Google found me this too: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samlester/2013/09/23/eomonth-equivalent-in-sql-server-2008-r2-and-below/

Comment: Larnu In my table data is already stored in integer format. I just want to get last date of month by converting it to a specific format. After I get last day of month I want to compare it in if statement like..if(datepart(dd,eomonth(column)))='31' but the problem is column is in integer format.

Comment: Yes, so I repeat by question in my original comment *"Why are you storing dates as an `int`? You're should really be using the date and time data types; it's what they're for."* You're using the **wrong** data type. Fix the data type, fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this from the [reference](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-eomonth-function/). The given answer will not work for the integer data type but it will work in the `varchar` datatype date value. Storing Date values in integer is not a good idea, so as suggested by [Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484879/larnu) change the data type in either `date` or `varchar`.

```
SELECT 
   Day(EOMONTH(Cast('20191229' as Date))) end_of_month;
```

Comment: No, because integer can not be converted to date. But it will work with varchar. Here is an example https://rextester.com/XAQM47817

Comment: You can also do something like this: `SELECT DAY(EOMONTH(CAST(CAST(20191229 AS VARCHAR(10))AS DATE))) END_OF_MONTH;`

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко Yes.

Comment: Just noting that I did *not* recommend to use a `varchar`. Only the Date and Time data types are the correct data types for a date/time.

Comment: This option doesn't  work in Sql Server 2008 R2 or SQL Server 2005. Showing below error [ Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'EOMONTH' is not a recognized built-in function name. ]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the amount of days within a month, as you need the days as an integer, you should go for this. This is the most robust built, but also the more complex one, as to make sure the `Integer` value is processed correctly:

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAY,EOMONTH(CAST(CAST('20191229' AS NCHAR(8)) AS DATE))) AS Days
```

Result:

```
Days
31
```

Comment: I want to use if condition here like if(datepart (dd,eomonth(column))='31' ) and same statement like you but when I try to put column name instead of date I get error like invalid column.

Comment: Why do you need to cast a string literal to varchar(10)? And why does that cast need to be varchar and not char? And why 10 characters and not 8? Sloppy code!

Comment: @SMor sorry for being a bit sloppy, it has been updated now. Thought it would be understood anyhow. A nicer tone instead of just ranting would be appreciated - or even better, feel free to edit next time.

Comment: Atmira thanks for the help it worked i just used 1 extra variable to store this and used that variable in my if statement: IF(DATEPART(day, EOMONTH(@MINdate)) = 31)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an IF evaluation to your selected date(s), you can do this by add an IIF-clause where it evaluates whether or not the end of month is 31 or not. If you want to use a columnname instead of the date, just substitute `@Date` with the columnname. I've just added the variable `@Date` instead of '20191229' to make it more illustrative/understandable. You can change the True/false descriptions to whatever you like in the query.

```
DECLARE @Date AS int
SET @Date = '20191229'

SELECT 
IIF (
    DATEPART(DAY,EOMONTH(CAST(CAST(@Date AS NCHAR(8)) AS DATE))) = '31'
    ,'True'
    ,'False'
    ) AS Days
```

Output:

```
Days
True
```