# Cognos report studio last day of month

Tags: cognos

I'm using the following filter, but it's not including any transactions from the last day of the month.  I think this filter assumes 12:01am.  I need to include through 11:59:59PM.

[TRL_DATE]<=_last_of_month(?ReportDate?)

Comment: If either of those are timestamps, cast them as dates.

Comment: What database are you using?  This link may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646585/sql-query-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month

Answer (score 0):

```
cast([TRL_DATE], date) <= cast(_last_of_month(?ReportDate?), date)
```