# Best Practice in Scenario

Tags: sql, t-sql, week-number, monthcalendar

I am currently trying to accomplish the following:

get the Last Weekstamp for the last 6 Months, the following ilustrates how the end result might look like:

```
Month  | Weekstamp |
2013-12| 2013-52   |
2014-01| 2014-05   |
```

.... and so on

I have a auxiliary Table, which has all Weeks in it and allows me to connect to a Calender Table, which in turn has all months, meaning i am able to get all weekstamps per Month,

but how do i get all of the Last Week Numbers for the Last 6 Months ?
my idea was a Temporary table of some sor (never used one, am a beginner when it Comes to SQL)
which calculates all of the Weekstamps needing to be filtered out per month, and than gives out only values which i could than use to filter a query which contains all the data i Need.

Anybody have a better idea?

As i said I am just a beginner so i can't really say what the best way would be

Thanks a lot in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your challenge is determining what the last six months are. To do this you can use a tally table (spt_values) and DateDiff to determine when the last six months are.

You can also depending on which DB and version easily do this without a calander or weeks table.

This

```
WITH rnge 
     AS (SELECT number 
         FROM   master..spt_values 
         WHERE  type = 'P' 
                AND number > 0 
                AND number < 7), 
     dates 
     AS (SELECT EOMONTH(Dateadd(m, number * -1, Getdate())) dt 
         FROM   rnge) 
SELECT Year(dt)         year, 
       Month(dt)        month, 
       Datepart(wk, dt) week 
FROM   dates
```

Produces this output

```
| YEAR | MONTH | WEEK |
|------|-------|------|
| 2014 |     1 |    5 |
| 2013 |    12 |   53 |
| 2013 |    11 |   48 |
| 2013 |    10 |   44 |
| 2013 |     9 |   40 |
| 2013 |     8 |   35 |
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15070)

I'll leave it to you to format the values

This assumes SQL Server 2012 since it uses EOMONTH see [Get the last day of the month in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1051488/119477) for previous versions of SQL Server