# Function get the last day of month in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the last day of month with input of month and year. For example, with input 06/2016 it will return 30. I use SQL Server 2005. Thanks for any help.

Comment: asked a bazillion times in a billion ways already. Please try searching!~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the last day of the month in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051488/get-the-last-day-of-the-month-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your input is `VARCHAR` in the form of `MM/YYYY`.

Use `RIGHT` and `LEFT` to get the year and month respectively. Then use `DATEFROMPARTS` to generate the starting date. Next, use `EOMONTH` to get the last day of the month. Finally use `DAY` to extract the day part.

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(7) = '06/2016'

SELECT
    DAY(
        EOMONTH(
            DATEFROMPARTS(CAST(RIGHT(@input,4) AS INT),CAST(LEFT(@input, 2) AS INT),1)
        )
    )
```

*The above only works for SQL Server 2012+.*

---

For SQL Server 2005, you can use `DATEADD` to generate the dates:

```
SELECT
    DAY( -- Day part
        DATEADD(DAY, -1, -- Last day of the month
            DATEADD(MONTH, CAST(LEFT(@input, 2) AS INT), -- Start of next month
                DATEADD(YEAR, CAST(RIGHT(@input, 4) AS INT) - 1900, 0) -- Start of the year
            )
        )
    )
```

Reference:

- [Some Common Date Routines](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/)

Comment: But I use Sql server 2005, so don't have eomonth.

Comment: Thanks @Felix Pamittan. It works and the reference very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
select eomonth(getdate(), 0);
```

If you want it formatted as MM/YYYY then you'd do this:

```
select format(eomonth(getdate(), 0), 'MM/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me for tossing-in a response that is not *specific to* "SQL Server," nor thence to "2005," but the **generalized** way to compute the answer that you seek is as follows:

1. Break down the input that you have, e.g. `06/2016`, into two parts. Call 'em `@MONTH` and `@YEAR`.  Define a third value, `@DAY`, equal to **1**.
2. Typecast this into a date-value ... "June 1, 2016."
3. Now, using the date-handling functions that you're *sure* to have, "first add one month, then subtract one day."

One thing that you must be ***very*** careful of, when designing code like this, is to be certain(!) that your code for decoding `06/2016` works for *every(!)* value that actually occurs in that database, **or** that it can be relied upon to *fail.*

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
declare @input varchar(20)='06/2016'
set @input=@input+'/01'
declare @dtinput datetime=@input


select  dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@dtinput)+1,0))
--OR in sql server 2012
select eomonth(@dtinput)
```