# SQL How do i change my batch_date column from first day of the month to last day of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssms

I'm working in SQL Server Management Studio 2008. I have a column called BATCH_DATE which has entries in this format `2007-01-01 00:00:00`. 
I need these to be changed into `2007-01-31 00:00:00` format. Please help.

BhatiaAshish answered my question and i already pressed the green checkmark for him/her. This question is answered.

Comment: @NEER - That's what he says in the question header!  Microsoft invented a command to do that - although I like to take DAY-1 days off, add a month and knock off a day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the last day of the month in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051488/get-the-last-day-of-the-month-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Month Datetime
Set  @month='2007-01-01 00:00:00'
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@month)+1,0))
```

Comment: fair enough, doesn't that give the time as 23:59:59 though?  Not what was asked for

Answer (score 0):

You could add 30 days to each one:

```
select dateadd(day, 30, batch_date)
```

If that doesn't work, then clarify what you mean in your question.

Comment: Something like is exactly what i'm looking for, except what about the months that only have 30 days or 29?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @BATCH_DATE as datetime = '2007-01-01 00:00:00';

SET @BATCH_DATE = DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,1,@BATCH_DATE));

select @BATCH_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dateadd(day, -1, dateadd( month, 1, batch_date))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will this also work on months that have 29 or 30 days? In that case, you answered my question.

Comment: Yes, it will work