# <Resolved> Fetch last date of a month and last minute of that day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get last day of the month with time like

```
2023-01-31 23:59:59:000000
```

I'm able to get only the last day of the month with time stamp as

```
2023-01-31 00:00:00:000000
```

Comment: Step back one second from the first day of the following month?

Comment: Yes Jarlh, exactly

Comment: How are you going to use that date time value `2023-01-31 23:59:59:000000` ?

Comment: As Squirrel asked, why do you need it? Normally you would use a condition like `where DateTimeColumn < Tomorrow` rather than `where DateTimeColumn <= LastSecondOfTheDay`

Comment: Hi Dale, im need  that query to read a particular column data untill the last minute of the month.

i got this DATEADD(ss,-1,(DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))) this worked actually

Answer (score 0):

As jarlh said your best method is to add a day to the end of the month, then subtract a second (although if you really want the absolute maximum time I think you'd want to subtract 3 milliseconds).

EOMONTH -> Add 1 day -> Cast as datetime -> remove 1 second / 3 milliseconds. You have to cast as datetime because the EOMONTH function implicitly casts to a date

The code will be something like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, -1, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@currentDate)) AS DATETIME))
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@currentDate)) AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: If you use the recommended datetime datatype, `datetime2` you can have milliseconds, rather than 3 milliseconds.

Comment: i got this DATEADD(ss,-1,(DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))) and it worked Dale thanks for your solutions

Answer (score -1):

There are already similar questions with a lot of answers. You should find your anwer for sure:
[Get the last day of the month in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051488/get-the-last-day-of-the-month-in-sql)

SQL query to display end date of current month

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATE = GETDATE()
SELECT EOMONTH (@currentDate) AS CurrentMonthED
```

SQL query to display end date of Next month

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATE = GETDATE()
SELECT EOMONTH (@currentDate, 1 ) AS NextMonthED
```

Comment: neither of these will add the required time component

Comment: Hi Vanessa, i tried this and it worked 

DATEADD(ss,-1,(DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)))